# Connect to database hosted on SSH machine with Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, ssh

I would like to connect to an Oracle database hosted on a remote box using Oracle SQL Developer. I am able to create a standard connection BUT I have to be connected to a VPN for security reasons. I want to bypass this vpn.

I do this all the time with normal ssh connections. There is one machine (gateway) on my company network than can be accessed outside the network (no vpn). From gateway, I can connect to any machine on our network. I would like to connect to the database hosted on machine (dbmachine) on the network (which cannot be accessed without being on the vpn unless I am first connected to the gateway).

This seems to be a common issue because I was easily able to bake this functionality seamlessly into my ssh config. Example:

```
Host gateway
     HostName gateway.company.org
     User marc

Host dbmachine
     HostName dbmachine.company.org
     User marc
     ProxyJump gateway

Host exampleMachine
     HostName exampleMachine.company.org
     User marc
     ProxyJump gateway
```

By using `ProxyJump`, I am able to type `ssh dbmachine` to seamlessly connect to dbmachine or `ssh exampleMachine` to seamlessly connect to exampleMachine. I want to do a similar jumping technique with Oracle SQL Developer. How can I connect to the database on dbmachine from Oracle SQL Developer?

I'm not sure what port the db is running on dbmachine, but I can access it though sqlplus when I'm logged into the box.

Comment: Open a tunnel: `ssh GATEuser@GATEhost -L LOCALport:DESThost:DESTport -N`. Then just connect to the local port `LOCALport`  in your machine, as it it was a local Oracle running in your machine.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is to create an SSH Tunnle:

`ssh -L 1521:localhost:1521 -N -f dbmachine`

This will forward all traffic on localhost:1521 to dbmachine:1521 (where the database is running). It will respect the user's configuration so you do not have to setup two tunnles.

-N Will not switch to remote shell
-f Requests ssh to go to background just before command execution

I'm not sure if there's a better solution that is configurable directly in a database client, but this works for me on Arch Linux.

Comment: This is correct. A database client does not deal with the networking setup or topology. The tunnel needs to be set up in advance.